# Using .svg in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, assets, content-generation, svg

Creating resolution independent sprites is tough and memory consuming.

How can .svg assets be used in Unity for any kind of 2D game?

What are alternatives to .svg that can be used in Unity?

Can sprites with various shapes be generated within Unity?

We would like to create universal art assets that'll support all devices with different resolutions. (We'll handle the aspect ratio )

Comment: This is less of a specific question and more of a list of questions. It may get downvoted because it seems like your looking for discussion on workflow practices. The Unity Forums might be a better place to get an overview of working with textures in Unity.

Comment: A great plugin for using SVG graphics in Unity is [SVGImporter](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38258) – It's easy to use and has great support. it basically replaces sprites with scalable SVG graphics.

Comment: I think SVG Importer is not being supported now.
Instead, you can use Vector Graphics which is a preview package. You can get it in Package Manager.
Here is more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAyd5wSPQrM

Comment: Unity has an SVG to Texture converter package https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@1.0/manual/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Well, normally you would just produce 1 graphic at the highest resolution you will be publishing to. Then you would use the Unity tools for setting mip-map levels. You would then modify settings like 'pixel perfect' or 'texture type' (compressed, truecolor, etc.) to get the best look for the compression you choose.

> Creating resolution independent sprites is tough and memory consuming.

What do you mean?

You're either creating your graphics in a vector program like Inkscape or Illustrator, or you create them in a raster program like Gimp or Photoshop. The difficulty is only determined by your comfort level with your toolset.

> How can .svg assets be used in unity for any kind of 2d game?

With a plugin: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38258

> What are alternatives to .svg that can be used in unity?

You can use the Unity [LineRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html) or standard GL drawing methods. [This Post](http://www.everyday3d.com/blog/index.php/2010/03/15/3-ways-to-draw-3d-lines-in-unity3d/) has some good examples.

> Can sprites with various shapes be generated within unity?

They will be whatever shape you draw them.

> Would like creating universal art asset that'll support all devices with different resolutions.(we'll handle the aspect ratio )

This isn't a sentence. But, Unity won't change aspect ratio, unless you scale on only one axis.